# How do I use dplyr to generate a new column based on rowwise data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new column to a data frame which is based on a row-wise calculation.  Suppose I have a data frame such as this one:

```
x <-as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, 5, 2))

  V1 V2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10
```

If I want to do some rowwise operation to generate a new column, I can use rowwise() and do() to accomplish that.  For example:

```
y <- rowwise(x) %>% do (foo = .$V1 * .$V2)
```

I can even append this to the existing data frame as such:

```
y <- rowwise(x) %>% bind_cols(do (., foo = .$V1 * .$V2))
```

This all works, but the result isn't quite what I want.  The values in y$foo are lists, not numeric.

```
  V1 V2 foo
1  1  6   6
2  2  7  14
3  3  8  24
4  4  9  36
5  5 10  50
```

Looks right, but it isn't.

```
class(y$foo)
[1] "list"
```

So, two questions:

1. Is there a way to make the results numeric instead of lists?
2. Is there a better way I should be approaching this?

**Update:**
This is closer to what I am trying to do.  Given this function:

```
pts <- 11:20
z <- function(x1, x2) {
  min(x1*x2*pts)
}
```

This doesn't produce what I expect:

```
y <- x %>% mutate(foo = z(V1, V2))
  V1 V2 foo
1  1  6  66
2  2  7  66
3  3  8  66
4  4  9  66
5  5 10  66
```

while this does:

```
y <-rowwise(x) %>% bind_cols( do (., data.frame(foo = z(.$V1, .$V2))))
  V1 V2 foo
1  1  6  66
2  2  7 154
3  3  8 264
4  4  9 396
5  5 10 550
```

Why?  Is there a better way?

Comment: @Pascal how about just `x %>% mutate(foo = V1 * V2)`?

Comment: @David, your example works, but what I really want is to call a function on each row and that function appears to be applied to the columns, not the row.  I get a single answer for the whole function, not an individual one per row.

Comment: What type of function? Can you make your example more representative please?

Comment: @David, I updated the description.  See the function I am trying to call.  Once I call the function, things seem to become column-wise calculations instead of row-wise calculations.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ok, I wrote some vectorized version of your `z` function, see my answer (though I didn't test for efficiency).

Comment: Are `V1`, `V2` and `pts` all positive? If so, your function simplifies to `V1*V2*min(pts)`...I think you still need a better example if that's the case. By the way, I think your "update" could replace much of the original content, making the question a little more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just return a `data.frame` in your `do` statement:

```
y <- rowwise(x) %>% bind_cols(do(., data.frame(foo = .$V1 * .$V2)))
y
##   V1 V2 foo
## 1  1  6   6
## 2  2  7  14
## 3  3  8  24
## 4  4  9  36
## 5  5 10  50
y$foo
## [1]  6 14 24 36 50
```

In your updated question, you are missing the `rowwise` in the chain with the `mutate` statement, but have the `rowwise` in the chain with the `do` statement. Just add `rowwise` and you will get the same result.

```
x %>% rowwise %>% mutate(foo = z(V1, V2))
## Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
##   V1 V2 foo
## 1  1  6  66
## 2  2  7 154
## 3  3  8 264
## 4  4  9 396
## 5  5 10 550
```

Comment: This is the most direct answer to my question.  David's answer may be better, but requires more re-architecture.

Answer (score 6):

I generally don't believe in row wise operations in a vectorized language such as R. In your case you could solve the question with a simple matrix multiplications.

You could define `z` as follows

```
z <- function(x1, x2) {
  do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(tcrossprod(x1 * x2, pts)))
}
```

Than a simple `mutate` will do

```
x %>% mutate(foo = z(V1, V2))
#   V1 V2 foo
# 1  1  6  66
# 2  2  7 154
# 3  3  8 264
# 4  4  9 396
# 5  5 10 550
```

---

You could also enhance performance using the `matrixStats::rowMins` function (which is fully vectorized)

```
library(matrixStats)

z <- function(x1, x2) {
  rowMins(tcrossprod(x1 * x2, pts))
}

x %>% mutate(foo = z(V1, V2))
#   V1 V2 foo
# 1  1  6  66
# 2  2  7 154
# 3  3  8 264
# 4  4  9 396
# 5  5 10 550
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <-as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, 5, 2))

foo <- apply(x , 1 , function(x){
  prod(x)
})

#[1]  6 14 24 36 50

class(foo)

#[1] "numeric"

df_final <- cbind(x , foo)
```

Comment: Is apply better?  I was trying to stay with dplyr, but perhaps it isn't the right tool for the job?

Comment: @SteveRowe `apply` is worse. You just need `x %>% mutate(foo = V1 * V2)`. And you certainly don't need `dplyr` at all for such a simple operation. With base R you can just do `x$foo <- x$V1*x$V2`. This is basic arithmetics.

Comment: this solution uses base `R` and satisfies your request by outputting `foo` as numeric not a list , this how the apply function works , also it doesn't matter how many column you're trying to take product of

Comment: if you're working with a big dataset it's better to use `dplyr` or `data.table` for better performance